# Where does MacVim keep its themes?

Tags: macvim

I'm using MacVim and I am attempting to change the default theme. I have the following in my `.vimrc` file (and in `.gvimrc` as well):

```
 colorscheme macvim
```

But the theme remains unchanged. What am I doing wrong?

The file is read in without errors but the scheme doesn't change. Also, if I download alternate themes, where do they go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I have in my ~/.vimrc

```
if has("gui_running")
  syntax on
  set hlsearch
  colorscheme macvim
  set bs=2
  set ai
  set ruler
endif
```

Answer (score 8):

By default, you should put custom colorschemes/themes into: `~/.vim/colors`

Note that you may need to create the `.vim` directory in your home directory if it does not already exist.

After doing so, your :colorscheme command should automatically pick up the theme.

Answer (score 7):

> Where does macvim keep it's themes?

The themes that MacVim ships with can be found in

```
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/colors
```

but MacVim will also load any custom themes you have on disk. I use the rather awesome [Janus plugin distribution](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) with MacVim and Janus keeps all of its themes in `~/.vim/janus/vim/colors`. MacVim will load this in as well as the defaults.

> But the theme remains unchanged. What am I doing wrong?

MacVim loads both `~/.vimrc` and `~/.gvimrc`, in that order. Make sure that settings in `~/.gvimrc` aren't clobbering settings you're making in your `~/.vimrc` file.

Comment: I have my colorscheme files in `~/.vim/colors` but MacVim does not show them in the Syntax menu as Janus distribution does. Do you know which could be the problem? I installed MacVim via brew command.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a `~/.gvimrc` file and add

```
colorscheme solarized
```

or whatever colorscheme you want. That's all I had to do to get my `brewed` version of `macvim` working again. I had a conditional like the one at the top of the thread and that worked for sometime, but recently ( I think after an upgrade to OSX ) I had to add the `.gvimrc` file to get OceanicNext to work.